# Redeclaration of variable in range-based for loops

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, c++11

This code fails with GCC 4.8.1 but works with MSVC2013:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> V{1,2,3,4,5};

  for (auto i : V)
  {
    std::string i = "oups";
  }
}
```

**GCC 4.8.1 tells:**

```
prog.cpp:10:17: error: redeclaration of ‘std::string i’
     std::string i = "oups";
                 ^
```

Is it some bug in the MSVC 2013 compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug, but in GCC. C++11[stmt.ranged] clearly states that your range-based `for` loop is equivalent to this:

```
{
  auto && __range = (V);
  for ( auto __begin = __range.begin(),
             __end = __range.end();
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin ) {
    auto i = *__begin;
    {
      std::string i = "oups";
    }
  }
}
```

So the inner `i` should simply hide the loop-control `i` without any problems.

And, as this [live example](http://ideone.com/BdOlcv) shows, when spelled out like this, GCC actually accepts it just fine.

Comment: So you mean that range-based for and "normal for" are not supposed to behave the same?

Comment: @Korchkidu Yes, they do behave differently in this regard.

Comment: Yes, indeed. It seems that range-based for loops put the for-range-declaration in a "in-between" scope. So actually, redeclaring the variable in the outer scope is ok too. This is counter intuitive to say the least.

Comment: The for rage loop from [stmt.ranged] is not equivalent to what you wrote. There isn't a scope for the statements (`std::string i = "oups";` in your case)

Comment: @BЈовић Where does it differ? Note that I already substituted the `begin-expr` and `end-expr` by their definition according to the OP's situation and the bullet points. I am not providing the general definition of the range-based `for` loop, I am showing what the OP's loop is formally equivalent to.

Comment: @BЈовић The scope comes from the OP's code. Note that the *statment* in the grammar is the entire compound statement `{ std::string i = "outps"; }` in the OP's case.

Comment: basic.block.scope does claim: "Names declared in the ... for-range-declaration ... are local to the ... for ... and shall not be redeclared in a subsequent condition of that statement nor in the outermost block". Is this block not the outermost block referred to?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in GCC, as well as [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d67267999ceea61)

See [Range Based For-loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

*`for ( range_declaration : range_expression ){ loop_statement }`*

will be equivalent to

```
{
auto && __range = range_expression ; 
     for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
        __end = end_expr; 
        __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
           range_declaration = *__begin;
            {  // Notice brace
               loop_statement 
            } // Notice ending brace
} 
}
```

On another note, on Visual C++ 2013

```
for (auto i : V) std::string i = "oups"; 
       /* match this with equivalent for-loop
          loop-statement aren't in braces
      */
```

shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

c++11 [stmt.ranged] tells that the range-for loop expands into this :

```
{
  auto && __range = range-init;
  for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
        __end = end-expr;
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin ) {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

Contrary to other answers, I am claiming there are no scopes for the statements, and that this is a MSVC's bug (not gcc or clang).

Comment: The production for the range-based for loop is "`for` `(` *for-range-declaration* `:` *expression* `)` *statement*". There's no literal `{` in that production, meaning that the *statement* in the OP's case is the entire compound statement.