# C++11 redeclaration in range-based for loop

Tags: c++11, for-loop, visual-c++

This code compiles in Visual Studio 2015 update 3 (and here: [visual C++ compiler online](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) , and does not in other compilers I have tried online (GCC and CLANG), giving a redeclaration error

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
for (auto i : v) {
  printf("%d ", i);
  int i = 99;
  printf("%d ", i);
}
```

> output: 1 99 2 99 3 99

VS C++ online compiler (version: 19.10.24903.0) warns about this:

> warning C4456: declaration of 'i' hides previous local declaration

Is there some space in the C++11 spec to allow for both implementations to be valid?

Seems to me that VS2015 is creating a scope for the "auto i", and an inner scope for the loop body.

Adding an extra scope, as a colleague suggested, compiles fine in the other compilers I have tested (not that I wanted this, it's just for curiosity):

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
for (auto i : v) {{
  printf("%d ", i);
  int i = 99;
  printf("%d ", i);
}}
```

thanks

**EDIT:**
Ok, after reading this other question [Redeclaration of variable in range-based for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526131/redeclaration-of-variable-in-range-based-for-loops) and the answer from "Angew", I believe that VS is actually correct.

I am reading here: [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Given this grammar description:

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

and what this is equivalent to:

```
{
 auto && __range = range_expression ; 
 for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; 
  __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
    range_declaration = *__begin; 
    loop_statement
 } 
}
```

I understand that **loop_statement** is actually my entire block including the brackets, so the redefinition is indeed in an inner block, hence valid.

**EDIT 2:**
My last edit, for future reference, reading the traditional **for loop** grammar is a similar situation ([cpp for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)) as the range-based:

```
for ( init-statement condition(optional); iteration_expression(optional) ) statement
```

"The above syntax produces code equivalent to:"

```
{
   init_statement 
   while ( condition ) { 
     statement 
     iteration_expression ; 
   }
}
```

So looking back, I could also interpret/parse **statement** as my inner block, including the braces, for which I would at least expect a consistent behavior in which ever compiler I am. But ALL compilers will bail out with a redeclaration error for the traditional for-loop.

Comment: I have just seen this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526131/redeclaration-of-variable-in-range-based-for-loops, which states that VS is actually right

Comment: for regular for loop being equivalent to while, you've cut off the EXCEPT part right after it, which talks about scopes of identifiers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N4606 (C++17 draft) 3.3.3 basic.scope.block, section 4 says

> Names declared in the
>   init-statement
>   , the
>   for-range-declaration
>   , and in the
>   condition
>   of
>   if
>   ,
>   while
>   ,
>   for
>   , and
>   switch
>   statements are local to the
>   if
>   ,
>   while
>   ,
>   for
>   , or
>   switch
>   statement (including the controlled statement),
>   and shall not be redeclared in a subsequent condition of that statement nor in the outermost block (or, for
>   the
>   if
>   statement, any of the outermost blocks) of the controlled statement; see 6.4

shortened:

> Names declared in the ... for-range-declaration ... are local to the ... for ... and shall not be redeclared in a subsequent condition of that statement nor in the outermost block

I read this as saying it should not be allowed.

Comment: But you can redeclare it in a nested context, right?

Comment: I will accept this as the answer, for the reference provided, although the lack of consistency in how different implementations interpret this grammar is troubling to say the least. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also surprised that the compilers still differ after a few years. But again, it's on how you read "statement nor in the outermost block". If that applies to the range-for's direct statement, then MSVC is right, but if it applies to the block in that location then GCC/Clang are right.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some space in the C++11 spec to allow for both implementations to be valid?

With one exception the only answer to that is no.

The exception is for global variables, where you can use the scoping operator `::` to reach them. Otherwise, if you *shadow* the name of a variable in an outer scope, you no longer have access to it.

Comment: The question was about the legality of the shadowing itself, not the accessibility of the shadowed variable.